# How to sort an arrange value in vector in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Assume that we have a vector as

```
A = [ 0 0 0 0 -1 2 -5 4 5 3 9 0 0 0 0 0]
```

How to sort a matrix with the value is increasing, and it could be become as

```
A = [0 0 0 0 -5 -1 2 3 4 5 9 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 4):

You can use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) and [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).

For example, assuming only 1 "island" of non-zeros:

```
A = [ 0 0 0 0 -1 2 -5 4 5 3 9 0 0 0 0 0];

A(A~=0) = sort(A(A~=0));
```

Returns:

```
>> A

A =

     0     0     0     0    -5    -1     2     3     4     5     9     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Hi, could you help me how can I take the position of these values? Thanks

Comment: Hi,
I want to find the position from A = [ 0 0 0 0 -1 2 -5 4 5 3 9 0 0 0 0 0];
and 
B =[7 5 6 10 8 9 11]